# Cesium GeoserverTerrainProvider plugin displays sharp cuts in altitude values beteween terrain tiles

Tags: geoserver, cesiumjs

My team and I are using the Cesium GeoserverTerrainProvider plugin but once the Digital Elevation Model is loaded, it isn't correctly displayed:

- Using "styled" image format or "bil/dds" plugin the terrain has little sharp cuts in the altitudes values right where there is a join of two terrain tiles
- Using "converted" image format(see below) the terrain has peaks of altitudes

to understand better you can take a look to the following link:
http://matteodipaolo.bitbucket.org/Geoserver/
the upper left buttons allows to load the terrain (in one of the three possible format - see below) while the tiles division is highlighted by whites lines drawns over the interested area in Spain.

The followings are the steps traced in order to manipulate and display Digital Elevation Model data

**Source Data:**
We use DEM data from the Spanish Geographic Institute

We are using Digital Elevation Model with 5 m resolution. The File format is ESRI ASCII grid (asc). Geodetic Reference System ETRS89 UTM projection in corresponding zone.

**Data processing:**
We are processing 2 ASC for our area of interest with GDAL :

We merge the original ASC files in a single GeoTIFF, with inner tiling, compression and NODATA values assignment

```
gdal_merge.py -o merged.tif -co "TILED=YES" -co "BLOCKXSIZE=512" -co "BLOCKYSIZE=512" -   co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "ZLEVEL=9" -init -999 -a_nodata -999 -n -999 -ot Int16 MDT05-1002-H30.asc MDT05-1003-H30.asc
```

We assign the correct CRS.

```
gdal_translate -a_srs "EPSG:25830" -co "TILED=YES" -co "BLOCKXSIZE=512" -co "BLOCKYSIZE=512" -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "ZLEVEL=9" merged.tif merged_CRS.tif
```

We create overviews

```
gdaladdo -r nearest --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW DEFLATE --config GDAL_TIFF_OVR_BLOCKSIZE 512 merged_CRS.tif 2 4 8 16 32 64
```

We create a 5 level pyramid

```
gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 5 -ps 1024 1024 -co "TILED=YES" -co "BLOCKXSIZE=512" -co "BLOCKYSIZE=512" -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "ZLEVEL=9" -targetDir pyramid/ merged_CRS.tif
```

**Serving in Geoserver:**
We have followed the instrucctions on https://github.com/kaktus40/Cesium-GeoserverTerrainProvider, using the BIL/DDS plugin.

**Cesium and Javascript code:**
We set a new Terrain Provider for viewer.scene.globe giving the possibility to choose between the geoserver plugin supported image formats:

1) STYLED:

```
var terrainProvider = new Cesium.GeoserverTerrainProvider({
            service: "WMS", 
            url : "http://geoserver.deimos-space.com/geoserver/elevation/wms",            
            xml: "http://geoserver.deimos-space.com/geoserver/elevation/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&tiled=true",
            layerName: "IGN_22_July_DEM_Pyramid_Transparent_Int16",                               
            styleName: "mySLD",
            hasStyledImage: true,
            formatImage: {format : "image/png",extension: "png"},
            formatArray: {
                format : "image/bil",
                /**
                * bufferIn : buffer to process (switch byte order and check the data limitations)
                * size: defines the dimension of the array (size.height* size.width cells)
                * highest: defines the highest altitude (without offset) of the data. 
                * lowest: defines the lowest altitude (without offset) of the data. 
                * offset: defines the offset of the data in order to adjust the limitations
                */
                postProcessArray : function(bufferIn, size,highest,lowest,offset) {
                    var resultat;
                    var viewerIn = new DataView(bufferIn);
                    var littleEndianBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(size.height * size.width * 2);
                    var viewerOut = new DataView(littleEndianBuffer);
                    if (littleEndianBuffer.byteLength === bufferIn.byteLength) {
                        // time to switch bytes!!
                        var temp, goodCell = 0, somme = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < littleEndianBuffer.byteLength; i += 2) {
                            temp = viewerIn.getInt16(i, false)-offset;
                            if (temp > lowest && temp < highest) {
                                viewerOut.setInt16(i, temp, true);
                                somme += temp;
                                goodCell++;
                            } else {
                                var val = (goodCell == 0 ? 1 : somme / goodCell);
                                viewerOut.setInt16(i, val, true);
                            }
                        }
                        resultat = new Int16Array(littleEndianBuffer);
                    }
                    return resultat;
                }
            }               
});
```

2) CONVERTED:

```
var terrainProvider = new Cesium.GeoserverTerrainProvider({
            service: "WMS", 
            url : "http://geoserver.deimos-space.com/geoserver/elevation/wms",            
            xml: "http://geoserver.deimos-space.com/geoserver/elevation/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&tiled=true",
            layerName: "IGN_22_July_DEM_pyramid_Transparent_Converted",
            hasStyledImage: false,         
            formatImage: {format : "image/png",extension: "png"},
            formatArray: {
                format : "image/bil",
                /**
                * bufferIn : buffer to process (switch byte order and check the data limitations)
                * size: defines the dimension of the array (size.height* size.width cells)
                * highest: defines the highest altitude (without offset) of the data. 
                * lowest: defines the lowest altitude (without offset) of the data. 
                * offset: defines the offset of the data in order to adjust the limitations
                */
                postProcessArray : function(bufferIn, size,highest,lowest,offset) {
                    var resultat;
                    var viewerIn = new DataView(bufferIn);
                    var littleEndianBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(size.height * size.width * 2);
                    var viewerOut = new DataView(littleEndianBuffer);
                    if (littleEndianBuffer.byteLength === bufferIn.byteLength) {
                        // time to switch bytes!!
                        var temp, goodCell = 0, somme = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < littleEndianBuffer.byteLength; i += 2) {
                            temp = viewerIn.getInt16(i, false)-offset;
                            if (temp > lowest && temp < highest) {
                                viewerOut.setInt16(i, temp, true);
                                somme += temp;
                                goodCell++;
                            } else {
                                var val = (goodCell == 0 ? 1 : somme / goodCell);
                                viewerOut.setInt16(i, val, true);
                            }
                        }
                        resultat = new Int16Array(littleEndianBuffer);
                    }
                    return resultat;
                }
            }               
});
```

3) BIL/DDS:

```
var terrainProvider = new Cesium.GeoserverTerrainProvider({
            service: "WMS", 
            url : "http://geoserver.deimos-space.com/geoserver/elevation/wms",            
            xml: "http://geoserver.deimos-space.com/geoserver/elevation/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&tiled=true",
            layerName: "IGN_22_July_DEM_Pyramid_Transparent_Int16",     
            hasStyledImage: false,      
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that the GeoserverTerrainProvider is the root cause of the odd elevations.  There is a lot of data manipulation in your work flow here; any of which could produce these artifacts.  To confirm, you may want to pull your GeoTIFFs into a tool like QGIS/ArcGIS and inspect the elevations along the tile edges.

The bigger problem is that for 5m resolution data, you are much better off using the quantized-mesh format for better transmission of the height data and more performant rendering.  When working directly with height maps, you are sending a lot of data to the client and Cesium must then tessellate the height map for each tile that is requested.  This will not scale if you plan to visualize the entire DEM dataset or add more 3d visualization to your application.

The only solution that will pregenerate quantized-mesh tiles is the STK Terrain Server (http://www.agi.com/products/stk/terrain-server/), and the good news is you will be able to create a tileset directly from the source asc files.  This is commercial software, but you can get a demo license and see how well it handles your data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to the Cesium SDk, but from the usage example: [Cesium Terrain Provider Usgae](https://github.com/kaktus40/Cesium-GeoserverTerrainProvider#usage)

And the Example : [Cesium Terrain Provider Example](https://github.com/kaktus40/Cesium-GeoserverTerrainProvider#example)

I noticed that they provide the StyleName property with the StyleName in the **mySLD.xml** not the File name (**mySLD.Xml**). And you used the (**Style FileName**) instead so try to use the StyleName from the file not the file name itself.

```
var terrainProvider = new Cesium.GeoserverTerrainProvider({
    url : "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/elevation/wms",
    layerName: "SRTM90",
    styleName:"grayToColor",
    waterMask:true
});
```

In Your Code:

```
styleName:"mySLD"
```

But in the Example:

```
styleName:"grayToColor"
```

I know it's so trivial but may be it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the gdal commands as it solved my problem (same as your):

`gdalwarp -ot Int16 -s_srs "EPSG:2154" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -dstnodata -32762 -r cubicspline -multi -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "ZLEVEL=6" *.asc outFolder/gray.tif`

`gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 3 -ps 2048 2048 -ot Int16 -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "ZLEVEL=6" -targetDir pyramidFolder outFolder/gray.tif`

See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cesium-dev/6aR35AuZ0mM/mVWaeKsPqg8J for the details.